# laravel sengrid random authentication failure when sending emails with attachment

Tags: laravel, sendgrid, laravel-9, laravel-mail

We are able to send out emails but a problem seems to occur when the email has an attachment.

we're getting this authentication error which is weird because we are able to send out no attachment emails so I'm not sure why it suddenly fails to authenticate.

> Symfony\Component\Mailer\Exception\TransportException: Failed to
> authenticate on SMTP server with username "myemail@email.com" using
> the following authenticators: "LOGIN", "XOAUTH2". Authenticator
> "LOGIN" returned "Expected response code "235" but got code "535",
> with message "535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the user
> credentials were incorrect. [xxx.xxx.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]".".
> Authenticator "XOAUTH2" returned "Expected response code "235" but got
> code "535", with message "535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful
> [xxx.xxx.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]".". in
> /var/www/project/vendor/symfony/mailer/Transport/Smtp/EsmtpTransport.php:198

Is this something related to our SendGrid configuration that we've missed? or could this be a server-related problem since our test server is able to send out emails with attachments fine? just this one live server is having the issue

Our test server is also using the same SendGrid account with a different API key and is able to send out emails with attachments okay.

We are using ubuntu and nginx